# HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found wcf routing on IIS server

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, .net-4.0, iis-7.5

I have the below mentioned settings in my WCF project but when I deploy it in IIS server I am getting 404 errors when I try to access my site like this: http://mysite.com/MyService
Global.asax:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("MyService", new AppServiceHostFactory(), typeof(UserService)));
    }
```

MyService.cs:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]

public class MyService : IMyService
{
```

Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>

<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                               </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"
                               aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: What is the `AppServiceHostFactory` that you are passing to the `RouteTable.Routes.Add` Method? Is it a custom service host?

Comment: yes it is.    public class AppServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
    {

Comment: Does AppServiceHostFactory have the same/similary functionality of WebServiceHostFactory